# How to change the iterative frequency in the following class

Tags: java

I used the following package

https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/FunctionGraph.java.html

Thecode goes like this

```
public class FunctionGraph {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // number of line segments to plot
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        // the function y = sin(4x) + sin(20x), sampled at n+1 points
        // between x = 0 and x = pi
        double[] x = new double[n+1];
        double[] y = new double[n+1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            x[i] = Math.PI * i / n;
            y[i] = Math.sin(4*x[i]) + Math.sin(20*x[i]);
        }

        // rescale the coordinate system
        StdDraw.setXscale(0, Math.PI);
        StdDraw.setYscale(-2.1, +2.1);

        // plot the approximation to the function
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            StdDraw.line(x[i], y[i], x[i+1], y[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the iterative interval to 0.1.

followed the following link for processing which is similar in syntax to java.

https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/19180/plot-graph.html

tried this type of syntax using the float

```
float y; 
 for (float x=-maxX; x < maxX; x+=.01) {
```

but its throwing an error showing declaration not possible in double. How to fix it.

Here is what i had done so far.

```
        // the function y = sin(4x) + sin(20x), sampled at N points
        // between x = 0 and x = pi
        float x ;
        float y ;
        for (float i = 0; i <= N; i+=0.1) {
            x = Math.PI * i / n;; // 10 grid points per second
            y=Math.sin(4*x[i]) + Math.sin(20*x[i]);;
        }

        // 
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the error message?

Comment: What error is it throwing? If that's *all* you changed, then I suspect you got several errors. `double[]` is an *array* of doubles; you can't replace it with a *single* `float` and expect to be able to graph all of the points line that. You have the right idea, but you need to finish making the changes.

Comment: Yup, what you said is right. I changed double and int to float everywhere.  Confused what to do next.

Comment: You can't index the array using float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using float in the for loop, I would use int but increase the increments as below.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        double[] x = new double[n+1];
        double[] y = new double[n+1];
        
        double t = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            x[i] = Math.PI * t / n ;
            y[i] = Math.sin(4*x[i]) + Math.sin(20*x[i]);
            System.out.printf("%10.4f%10.4f%10.4f\n", t, x[i], y[i]);
            t+=0.1;
        }
  }
```

Would output the following for n = 10

```
java Main 10
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
0.1000    0.0314    0.7131
0.2000    0.0628    1.1997
0.3000    0.0942    1.3192
0.4000    0.1257    1.0695
0.5000    0.1571    0.5878
0.6000    0.1885    0.0968
0.7000    0.2199   -0.1805
0.8000    0.2513   -0.1067
0.9000    0.2827    0.3170
1.0000    0.3142    0.9511
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I tried it as you mentioned, but its giving the following error.    >> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
 at homework1.FunctionGraph1.main(FunctionGraph1.java:11)

Comment: Why is your array has the length of zero?

Comment: Oh it's because you did not pass any parameter when you run your class.  Try passing a number to your program:     java FunctionGraph 5

Comment: Thank you very much it worked perfectly. I missed the small thing.

Comment: I made those kind of mistakes too.

Comment: I think, though the code is working, it may be wrong.  From the code you had given the points obtained are as follows >> 0.0:0.0
0.0:0.0
0.0:0.0
0.0:0.0
0.0:0.0
0.0:0.0
0.0:0.0
0.0:0.0
0.0:0.0
0.0:0.0
1.0:3.0756294287323476
1.0:3.0756294287323476
>> which means insted of interating from 0 to 0.1 then 0.2,0.3 etc its just iterating at 0.0 for 10 times, 1.0 for 10 times etc.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  I made some changes.  See if it's what you want.

Comment: Thank you i got the answer. I just tweaked the code you had given a little and i obtained what i needed. Homework completed :)